# I just want to know where we need to make changes while customizing odoo?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8, odoo-8

I am new in odoo. Can u please tell me where I need to customize an odoo business application. We have a database, XML, python files etc.

Is there any need to make change in view_XML, python or pg admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize an Odoo application you definitely don't have to change the database manually (I guess that's what you mean by pgadmin).

You should not make changes to core Odoo modules or any module for that matter, instead you should create your own modules to modify existing modules or add new features.

[Themes, snippets](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/themes.html) and basic view customizations (rearrange fields or show and hide existing model fields) doesn't require to write any python file (other than the required module python files).

If you want to make [extend current models or add new models](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#inheritance-and-extension)  then you need to create new python files

Answer (score -2):

The Best way to customize odoo Module is to build a new module.

For Creating new Module best tutorial is Technical Momento book and Document provided by odoo on www.odoo.com